# What is the process for changing and ratifying the EOS constitution?

Tags: constitution

1. Where is the repo for the constitution?
2. Where does one discuss edits / changes / concepts ?
3. Is the constitution supposed to be a block.one thing or a community thing?
4. How does one formally propose a new change, and create an election?

Comment: I think the title of this question could be made better.  Perhaps `"What is the change process for the EOS Constitution?"`

Answer (score 1):

here is the link to the repo of constitution https://github.com/cosmos/constitution/wiki/Research-EOS---Governance-and-Constitution It won't be controlled by block.one, hard forking changes will be accepted by Block Producers.

Comment: This looks really old. They had a newer one in the EOS repo for awhile. But still, I am curious as to how to edit, discuss, and propose for election. IMHO the one which was in the EOS repo needs a bit of work! – expaand yesterday